# F String With Special Characters

Tags: python, string, f-string

I want to print the following using an f string literal. It will be running wihtin a function and apples will be one of the arguments. I want it to have the square brackets included.

`"I like [apples] because they are green"`

I have tried the following code:

`"I like {} because they are green".format("apples")`

The code above prints:

`I like apples because they are green`

How do I insert the square brackets [ ] or another special character such as < > into the f string literal?

Comment: recognize that the "special character" is actually not special at all, it's just a string after all! If you need a string, it goes where all the other strings go. `"I like [{}] because they...`

Comment: another way (kind of magical, but oh well) to do it is this: `"I like {} because they are green".format(["apples"])`. It adds the brackets because you passed a list instead of just the atomic string.

Comment: Building on the previous comment, the only characters that are actually "special" within a formatting string (besides escaped characters, like in any other string), are the placeholder characters `{` and `}`. If you want to use them literally you have to duplicate them, so for example to get `I like {apples}` you need to do `"I like {{{}}}".format("apples")` (three pairs of braces, two for the literal braces and one for the placeholder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple possible ways to do this:

`"I like [{}] because they are green".format("apples")`
or
`"I like {} because they are green".format("[apples]")`.

If instead of brackets you wanted to use actual special characters, you would just have to escape in the appropriate place:

`"I like {} because they are green".format("\"apples\"").`

Additionally, if you wanted to use actual f-strings, you could do the same thing as above but with the format:

`f"I like {'[apples]'} because they are green"`

but make sure to switch from double quotes to single quotes inside the brackets to avoid causing troubles by ending your string early.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few suggestions on how to use special characters in f-string.

1. If you want to print

> Hello "world", how are you

```
var1 = "world"
print(f"Hello \"{var1}\", how are you")
```

2. To print:

> Hello {world}, how are you

where world is a variable

```
var1 = world 
print(f"Hello {{var1}}, how are you")
```

3. To print:

> Hello {world}, how are you

where world is a constant

```
print(f"Hello ""{world""}, how are you")
```

Answer (score 1):

To print:
Hello {world}, how are you

where world is a variable

```
var1 = world 
print(f"Hello {{var1}}, how are you")
```

is not correct. You have to add one extra bracket

```
var1 = world 
print(f"Hello {{{var1}}}, how are you")
```

since in f-string double brackets plots a single bracket